Cartier divisor from rational section of invertible sheaf?
This is continuing the answer in Each divisor arises from a rational section . Should the result be changed to a version like the following with some requirements of the scheme and the section?

Let $X$ be a integral or locally Noetherian scheme and $\mathscr{L}$ be an invertible sheaf on $X$ and $s$ be a regular rational section of $\mathscr{L}$. Then there is some Cartier divisor $D$ on $X$ such that $\mathscr{O}(D) \cong \mathscr{L}$?

I am mostly hesitating at two points:

Is requiring $X$ integral or locally Noetherian necessary or sufficient? Since only on integral or locally Noetherian cases the sheaf of meromorphic functions is the same as the sheaf of rational functions (G&W Prop 11.24), it seems necessary to require this.
Since Cartier divisor from definition is global section of $\mathcal{K}^{\times}/\mathcal{O}^{\times}$. It seems necessary to add some regularity condition, otherwise one can only construct sections of $\mathcal{K}$ rather than of $\mathcal{K}^{\times}$. But how should "regular rational section of an invertible sheaf" be defined? Should it be regular element on the biggest schematically dense open subset, or just just on an arbitrary one is enough?

I got two positive results maybe related from Görtz&Wedhorn’s algebraic geometry but found no discussion of Cartier divisors on Stacks project though:

Proposition 11.29. Let $X$ be a scheme. We assume that
(1) $X$ is integral, or
(2) $X$ is a locally noetherian scheme that contains an affine open subscheme $U$ that is schematically dense in $X$.
Then the homomorphism $\operatorname{Div}(X) \rightarrow \operatorname{Pic}(X), D \mapsto \mathscr{O}_X(D)$ is surjective and therefore induces an isomorphism
$$
\operatorname{DivCl}(X) \xrightarrow{\sim} \operatorname{Pic}(X) .
$$

and

Proposition 11.34. Let $X$ be a scheme, let $\mathscr{L}$ be a line bundle on $X$, and let $R_{\mathscr{L}}$ be the set of $s \in \Gamma(X, \mathscr{L})$ that are regular. Then there is a natural bijection between "effective Cartier divisors $D$ such that $\mathscr{O}_{X}(D) \cong \mathscr{L}$" and $R_{\mathscr{L}}/\sim$ where $s \sim s^{\prime}$ if there exists an $a \in \Gamma\left(X, \mathscr{O}_{X}^{\times}\right)$ with $s^{\prime}=as$.

